# Inserir coluna com função mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, brasil

Bom dia,

Sou iniciante e estou com uma dificuldade.

Tenho uma coluna chamada ID e é uma tabela de histórico, então esse id se repete algumas vezes
Eu queria uma coluna que retornassem quantas vezes esse id se repetiu, exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HÁ COMO?

Answer (score 1):

Em uma instrução select você pode utilizar o comando GROUP BY para agrupar os valores e depois utilizar o comando COUNT para contar as ocorrências, exemplo:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    COUNT(ID) AS total
FROM
    historico
GROUP BY
    ID
ORDER BY
    2
```

No exemplo acima, além de agrupar e contar os elementos, está ordenando pela segunda coluna.